# int object not subscriptable in python

Tags: python, neural-network

I was trying to convert my neural network node layer(in python), to be read more easily.
But it continuously said int object not subscriptable.

This is my code:-

```
# The input
inputs = [1, 2, 3, 2.5]

# The Weights
#weights1 = [0.2, 0.8, -0.5, 1.0]
#weights2 = [0.5, -0.91, 0.26, -0.5]
#weights3 = [-0.26, -0.27, 0.17, 0.87]

weights = [[0.2, 0.8, -0.5, 1.0], [0.5, -0.91, 0.26, -0.5], [-0.26, -0.27, 0.17, 0.87]]

# The Bais'
bias1 = 2
bias2 = 3
bias3 = 0.5

# Output goes here
output = [inputs[0]*weights[0[0]] + inputs[1]*weights[0[1]] + inputs[2]*weights[0[2]] + inputs[3]*weights[0[3]] + bias1,
          inputs[0]*weights[1[0]] + inputs[1]*weights[1[1]] + inputs[2]*weights[1[2]] + inputs[3]*weights[1[3]] + bias2,
          inputs[0]*weights[2[0]] + inputs[1]*weights[2[1]] + inputs[2]*weights[2[2]] + inputs[3]*weights[2[3]] + bias3]

print(output)
```

Comment: `weights[0[0]]` ಠ_ಠ `[0[0]]` ಠ_ಠ `0[0]` — *THAT* is you trying to subscript an int.

Comment: In `weights[0[0]]`, you're trying to use zero as an index for the number zero.  You probably wanted `weights[0][0]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`weights[0[0]]`, you are subscripting `0`, should be `weights[0][0]` instead. Same applies to all other accesses of the `weight` array